I can't install a module in python
./run_007-TheBond.sh: строка 10: python: команда не найдена
./run_007-TheBond.sh: строка 11: venvScriptsactivate: команда не найдена
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/007-TheBond/scripts/007-TheBond.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Search import WebSearch
  File "/home/user/007-TheBond/scripts/Search.py", line 2, in <module>
    from googlesearch import search
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlesearch'

please help, i dont know what to do :_(
I tried other people's advice, but it didn't help

Generally, if you have an error you don't understand, perform an online research first. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

you need to work in a virtual environment. type (on linux/MacOSX) python3 -m venv .venv to create one, . .venv/bin/activate to activate one and deactivate to deactivate one. Read more here.
